# How to fill missing values in a dataset with multiple timepoints but i only want to carry the last observation forward for each participant?

Tags: python, dataframe, missing-data

I have a python data frame with health data and participants appearing at timepoints 1, 2, and 3. I have a column called 'BPMEDS' with missing data, and a lot of it is the last time point that is missing (whether that is 1, 2, or 3). The last filled row for BP MEDS is above each empty row.
So 'randid' 16799 does not have 'bpmeds' for period 3, but does for period 2. I simply want to copy the value from the last available period. Each participant has an ID, so the ID can appear up to 3 times in the dataset.

```
 RANDID  BPMEDS  PERIOD
26   16799     0.0       1
27   16799     0.0       2
28   16799     NaN       3
29   19304     0.0       1
30   20375     0.0       1
31   20375     0.0       2
32   23727     1.0       1
```

If theres only period 1 available with an empty 'bpmeds' field then i will have to ignore this and come to it later.

I want to fill in the missing rows with the last observation available for each participant.

I'm not sure where, to begin with this.

```
for ind in df.index:
    if df['PERIOD'][ind] != '1':
       df['BPMEDS'][ind] = df.groupby(['RANDID']).fillna(method='ffill')
```

That is what I have tried and i get a value error and type error.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Please, consider to be more specific based on the data that you've showed. Try to explain your problem based on the column's name.  On the others hands, which columns you need to be completed?. In your example/image, there is only one missing-value in the column `BPMED` because others values are filled with 0 or another value, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

## The fillna() function iterates through your dataset and fills all null rows with a specified value.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' :[0, 3, None, 10, 3, None],
```

'B' : [None, None, 7.13, 13.82, 7, 7],
'C' : [None, "Pandas", None, "Pandas", "Python", "JavaScript"]})

This method involves replacing missing values with computed averages. Filling missing data with a mean or median value is applicable when the columns involved have integer or float data types.

#To insert the mean value of each column into its missing rows:

```
df.fillna(df.mean().round(1), inplace=True)
```

#For median:strong>
df.fillna(df.median().round(1), inplace=True)
print(df)

Inserting the modal value as you did for the mean and median above doesn't capture the entire DataFrame. But you can insert it into a specific column instead, say, column C:

```
df['C'].fillna(df['C'].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```

Comment: I dont want to fill with a mean or median but just with the value from the previous row for column 'bpmeds'  where the 'randid' is the same